# Do captured supplies supply my troops?

Tags: ultimate-general-civil-war

In ultimate general civil war, when capturing hostile supply units, will they supply my own troops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, captured supplies supply your troops in exactly the same way as friendly supplies do.